# How to change the value of a Text Box depending on the currently selected row within a Data Grid?

Tags: c#, winforms

Hi I'm hoping someone can help,

I have a Data Grid that has X amount of rows and I have a Text Box at the bottom of my form called 'Notes', I want the user to be able to select a row then enter a note within the Text Box and store this so when the user selects a different row the Text Box will be blank available for notes to be added for the new row. Then if the user selects a row that they have added notes to the Text Box will contain those notes.

I hope that makes sense, any ideas on how to approach this would be really appreciated.

Thanks,

Ryan

Comment: do you save the notes in database table which you against selected row id??

Comment: Hi @ArsalanQaiser that would be the idea yes, to have the notes saved on the same row in the database

Comment: get the id of the selected row based on that id select the notes from database table

Comment: I haven't inserted the notes into the database yet as I want to do it on a row by row basis (each row is a property). I need to have the notes for each row stored and then I will insert everything with my stored procedure.

Comment: another thing is you maintain a dictionary and saved against the row index you can get that on selected. but it is temparary basis

Comment: did you bind the datagrid to a bindingsource ? If so, just bind the TextBox to the same bindingsource and your done

Comment: @GuidoG So simple, that seems to have done the trick, thanks really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to GuidoG I have solved this, just in case anyone else has the same issue what I did was add a data binding to the grid then set the parameters. "Text" is just the property name, MyDataTable is the data source for my grid and "Notes" is the column name.

```
MyGrid.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Text", MyDataTable, "Notes"));
```